# JavaScript-Dynamically created variables -Excel Logic-Html Input

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am applying some basic excel logic into  HTML inputs. I am calling the formulas from database (i.e  E2=A1-A3 )
Currently my rows ( actually cells) have names and Ids like A1,A2,A3

At the same time when I load the number of cells I want to dynamically create the variable names and place the formulas from database like.

- I have fixed number of columns (A,B,C,D,E,F)
- Number of rows are dynamic.
- what I am currently trying and thinking is something like this;

(number of cells also comes from  database)

```js
for(var i=0; i<numberofRows; ++i){
    var  A+i=document.getElementById("A"+i).value; 
    var  B+i=document.getElementById("B"+i).value;
 }
```

- I want to use something like this or something similar.
- Or should I change cell names as  A[1], B[2], B[3] if I do it this way then how can I get the value of element via document?  like :

  ```
  var B=[];
  B[i]= document.getElementById(B[i]).value;
  ```

Comment: `B[i]= document.getElementById('B' + i).value;` is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested array to store the data:

```
var excelArr = [];
for (var x = 0; x < numColumns; x++)
    excelArr[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < numRows; y++)
        excelArr[x][y] = 12345; // Formula or Data
```